# JS how to call a function inside a function with arguments of a parent function?

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments, call, bind

I need help with typical case but I have no idea how to do this without dirty things like for .. in .. or forEach.
So, i have an object with some methods and bool field which shows, need to print log or not. Something like that:

```
var sender = {
  showLogs: true,
  doSomething: function(){
    "do something";
    if (this.showLogs)
      console.log("Sender do something")
  }
}
```

Obviously, there will be a lot of same code, repeating on every method:

```
if(this.showLogs)
  console.log("Sender do x");
```

Best practice is to move this code into new method:

```
..
log: function(message){
  if (this.showLogs)
    console.log(message)
}
..
```

And call this method instead of repeating if... passage:

```
  ..
  doSomething: function(){
    "do something";
    this.log("Sender do something");
  }
 ..
```

But what if I need to log unknown quanity of arguments in one log, like:

```
this.log("Start at: ", start time,", Value send: ", data);
```

So, the question is: how can i call console.log inside my function with the same parameters, no matter how much of them was sended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Function#apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) along with [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to call a function with the arguments that were passed to the parent function.

```
log: function(message){
  if (this.showLogs)
    console.log.apply(null,arguments);
}
```

You can also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with arguments, which makes it so you do not have to call `.apply`

```
log: function(message){
  if (this.showLogs)
    console.log(...arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you format your message with x parameters before calling the log function so that you only have one formatted String to log ?

Comment: Not the thing i need, but nice idea too/